# Getting IP address of domain plus the back server information

Tags: ruby, networking

How do you get the IP address of a domain and the server information of that domain, to tell if the server info is Apache, nginix, etc..?

I have a pretty good idea on how to get the IP, but for some reason it won't output the correct information:

```
require 'socket'
IPSocket::getaddress('http://www.prairiegraphicdesign.com/phpStuff/week2Shopping/cartAdd.php?action=add&id=4') 
#<= irb(main):001:0> require 'socket'
#    => true       
#    irb(main):002:0>IPSocket::getaddress('http://www.prairiegraphicdesign.com/phpStuff/week2Shopping/cartAdd.php?action=add&id=4')
#   SocketError: getaddrinfo: No such host is known.
#        from (irb):2:in `getaddress'
#        from (irb):2
#        from C:/Ruby22/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Is this because I need to strip the URL down to the original URL?

```
http://www.prairiegraphicdesign.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a URL, and `getaddress` has no idea what to do with those. All it can handle is fully-qualified domain names (FQDN) like "example.com".

Instead you need to break it out:

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse('http://www.prairiegraphicdesign.com/phpStuff/week2Shopping/cartAdd.php?action=add&id=4')

uri.host
#=> "www.prairiegraphicdesign.com"
```

You can resolve that to an address if you like.

As for what server software it's running, you need to make an HTTP request to the server and extract the right header from the response:

```
require 'net/http'

res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)

res['server']
#=> "Microsoft-IIS/6.0"
```

Comment: That makes sense, so I could resolve the address with socket after it's been parsed correct?

Comment: There's a number of ways to resolve it, including the `Socket` library. For more detail you could try [Net::DNS](https://github.com/bluemonk/net-dns) where it will give you a list of records, not just A type.